# Starcluster, how to do a specific task on separate node

Tags: python, node.js, multithreading, mpi4py, starcluster

Working on a python application that process high statistical data and perform long complex calculation.

When user requests an async thread has been created and starts the calculation and save the results in the database at an equal interval, where as at the main thread we keep looking for changes in database and update the user with the results.

Now I'm asked to use MIT's Starcluster that works with AWS. I have created master and slave clusters now **my question is how to use MPI4py to to perform the calculation at node (slave) machine and all other things at master?**

I haven't written any code but I found an example that is showing how it works in the sense of load balancing,

- https://gist.github.com/brantfaircloth/2379572

Is there any way I can call a specific api at node machine to perform a task at the node machine?

Comment: How do you manage your jobs? Do you want to use OGS/SGE for dispatching or do you want to launch your job directly on the nodes?

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers your question but I will use `MPI.COMM_WORLD` and its `send()` and `recv()` methods to communicate between master and nodes

Comment: So your question has more to do with MPI than StarCluster. I can't really help you then.

Comment: I'm not sure How it will work, When I google around I find this https://gist.github.com/brantfaircloth/2379572 and this https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/distributed-parallel-programming-python-mpi4py/ examples. I thought this will be enough for using `PYTHON` + `STARCLUSTER`

Comment: @Finch_Powers my objective is to perform a specific task at node server which will free the master server main thread and shift load of calculation to other node machine,

Comment: @Finch_Powers can you please guide me what should I use? and is there any example available for OGS and SGE

Comment: I've never worked with MPI so it's outside my expertise. If you want to schedule jobs with OGS, you can use the qsub or qrsh command and request a specific resource (node in this case) with the "-l" flag. The command would look like "qrsh -l hostname=<target hostname> <your executable>"

Comment: can I do the same with in the python using some interface/api? or I need to call sh commands from python? since I need to achieve this with in my python code.

Comment: I think you have to use sh commands. I haven't really dug the subjet.